# SQL - "not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2016.  I have a table:

```
Product   Qty   OrderDate
--------------------------
Toys      100   2018-10-01
Toys      100   2018-10-01
Books      30   2018-10-01
Toys      150   2018-10-02
Toys       50   2018-10-02
Toys       20   2018-10-02
Toys      110   2018-10-03
Toys       90   2018-10-04
Toys      200   2018-10-05
Toys      100   2018-10-05
Toys       30   2018-10-08
Toys       50   2018-10-09
```

and I want to calculate the average quantity per product, for the last 5 days.  I am close to this with this query:

```
SELECT 
  Product,
  RowNumber, 
  OrderDate, 
  AVG(TotalQty) OVER (ORDER BY RowNumber DESC ROWS 5 PRECEDING) as RollingAvg
FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY orderDate) AS RowNumber, Product, OrderDate, sum(Qty) as TotalQty
  FROM Tbl 
  GROUP BY Product, OrderDate
) x
GROUP BY Product, RowNumber, OrderDate
```

The inner query works correctly, giving me the total per product/date pair.  However my outer query reports a problem:

```
Column 'x.TotalQty' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

There's obviously something I'm doing wrong with my OVER clause, because when I remove *that* I get a valid result.

Syntactically valid query (that does the wrong thing):

```
SELECT 
  Product,
  RowNumber, 
  OrderDate, 
  AVG(TotalQty) as RollingAvg
FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY orderDate) AS RowNumber, Product, OrderDate, sum(Qty) as TotalQty
  FROM Tbl 
  GROUP BY Product, OrderDate
) x
GROUP BY Product, RowNumber, OrderDate
```

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated please - I'm close but can't cross this final hurdle!

Comment: With your given sample data, can you show us the desired output? ...just to make sure we understand the problem.

Comment: In your first query, you can simply remove the `group by`. Since you are using a windowed function, a `group by` is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT Product, RowNumber, OrderDate, 
       AVG(TotalQty) OVER (ORDER BY RowNumber DESC ROWS 5 PRECEDING) as RollingAvg
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY orderDate) AS RowNumber,
             Product, OrderDate, sum(Qty) as TotalQty
      FROM Tbl 
      GROUP BY Product, OrderDate
     ) x;
```

That is, the outer aggregation is unnecessary because `AVG()` is being used as a window function, not an aggregation function.

You should be able to do this without a subquery:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY orderDate) AS RowNumber,
       Product, OrderDate, sum(Qty) as TotalQty,
       AVG(SUM(Qty)) OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY orderDate ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as avg_5
FROM Tbl 
GROUP BY Product, OrderDate;
```

Note that this interprets "last five days" as the current day plus the preceding four days.  Your version has six days for the average.

Comment: This has solved it - thank you!  I also wanted ORDER BY RowNumber ASC (not DESC), but that was a relatively minor fix.